# Команды и их последовательность Delphi

Tags: delphi

Есть код:

```
procedure TForm1.sButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  sArcPreloader1.Visible := True; //появление лоадера
  SButton1.Enabled := False;
  HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil); //проверка интернет-соединения
  HTTP.HandleRedirects := True;
  try
    HTTP.Get('http://www.google.com');
  except
    ShowMessage('You have no internet connection.');
    Form1.Close;
  end;
end;
```

При выполнения данного кода сперва проверяется интернет-соединение, а потом уже появляется лоадер.
Как сделать так, чтобы сперва появлялся лоадер, а потом уже проверялось интернет-соединение?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Чтобы обновились состояния визуальных компонентов, надо выполнить `Application.ProcessMessages;`

```
sArcPreloader1.Visible := True; // Флаг видимости
Application.ProcessMessages; // реальное появление лоадера
```

http://www.delphi-manual.ru/processmessages.php

Comment: Всё правильно. Но, когда запускаю программу появляется лоадер и всё зависает. Когда прорамма проверила на наличие соединения, она отвисает и лоадер начинает крутится. Можно ли зделать так, чтобы программа не зависала: лоадер крутился, а програма проверяла соединение?

Comment: Возможно тут решение? http://delphidevelop.ru/publ/tidhttp_otobrazhenie_progressa/12-1-0-328/

Comment: Зачем поощрять использование ProcessMessages? Это же зло в чистом виде, хотя и не настолько кристаллизованное как Goto. Значительно правильнее использовать TThread.ForceQueue. Кроме того -вы не обратили внимание ТС-а, что у него утечка памяти в коде. С учетом того, что это Indy - весьма не маленькая утечка. Я уже не говорю про обращение к Self через внешнюю переменную Form1.

Answer (score -2):

Юзай goto, создай обратную версию цикла с предисловием I:=0 если i<>1 then присвоить i+1, переход к строке дальше, строка возвращает обратно но уже с переменной i=1 и выполняется условие. Или 2 потока и держать в паузе выполнение 2.